# sed not replacing some spaces

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am having some trouble getting SED to work right.

Input file:

```
$ cat txt

# nasty comment
blah blah blah this line is invalid
; this also isn't right
foo = 23 # comment here
blah=76876.8768 -- fubar
    yoyo=76
  tab_moo = -45.99
// comment
fubar = baz
#dfgpo=sf
####
```

Now how I parse it:

```
$ cat txt | sed -r 's/(#|--|;|\/\/).*//' | grep '=' | sed -r 's/[[:blank:]]+//'
foo= 23 
blah=76876.8768
yoyo=76
tab_moo = -45.99
fubar= baz
```

The goal is to remove all comments and all inline whitespace.

I don't get why some spaces are left in the output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Minor note, `-r` is a GNUism.  If you change it to `-E` it will work on both GNU and non-GNU versions of `sed` (e.g. BSD, Macs, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

In `sed`, `s///` only replaces the first occurrence on any given line.  You need to add `/g` on the end:

```
sed -r 's/[[:blank:]]+//g'
```